# Trying to follow a tutorial to build a spring boot vuejs project but get some errors

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs to build a spring boot with vuejs project, I have created the empty vue project using `vue create frontend --no-git` and then till this step: "Calling a REST service with Axios is simple. Go into the script area of your component, e.g. Hello.vue and add:"

```
import axios from 'axios'

data ();{
  return {
    response: [],
    errors: []
  }
},

callRestService ();{
  axios.get(`api/hello`)
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.response = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
}
}
```

I don't know where exactly this should be added. I created my Hello.vue file under frontend\src\views folder like this and I added it in the src\router\index.js

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button class=”Search__button” @click="callRestService()">CALL Spring Boot REST backend service</button>
    <h3>{{ response }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

data ();{
  return {
    response: [],
    errors: []
  }
},

callRestService ();{
  axios.get(`api/hello`)
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.response = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
}
}
</script>
```

But the npm run build gives me this error:

```
C:\gitercn1\spring-boot-vuejs-copy\frontend\src\views\Hello.vue: 'return' outside of function (13:4)

  11 |
  12 |   data ();{
> 13 |     return {
     |     ^
  14 |       response: [],
  15 |       errors: []
  16 |     }
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon in `data ();{`.

Comment: @Ricky Do you mean like this `data (){`? Then it shows this error: Syntax Error: SyntaxError: C:\gitercn1\spring-boot-vuejs-copy\frontend\src\views\Hello1.vue: Unexpected token, expected ";" (11:7)

Comment: Check StartedFromTheBottom's answer, they give a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must add `callRestService()` in `methods` or handler (as you are calling the method on button click).

Second, you should remove the unnecessary `;` after `data()` and `callRestService()`.

Third, you should `export` and `name` your component if you're going to reuse it somewhere.

Inside your `Home.vue` component, it could look like so:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button class=”Search__button” @click="callRestService()">CALL Spring Boot REST backend service</button>
    <h3>{{ response }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    name: "HelloComponent",
    data() {
      return {
        response: [],
        errors: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      callRestService() {
        axios.get(`api/hello`)
          .then(response => {
            // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
            this.response = response.data
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```